# Western red cedar vs pressure treated / GC timbers for exterior load bearing beams

Tags: wood, framing, structural, lumber

For exterior exposed load bearing timbers and support beams, is western red cedar sufficiently weather resistant or is ground contact (GC) pressure treated a significantly superior option?

There will be no ground contact (tree house use case). South central US location (not ultra humid like the gulf coast but also not arid).

Comment: Your local weather conditions will matter plus the amount of ground contact.  Edit these into your question.

Comment: Details have been added @crip659 - thanks

Comment: Probably both will work well and would come down to a cost and availability of product locally.  Should wait till more experience people comment/answer.

Comment: I find cedar outlasting treated lumber but the next would be to compare the strength. I have built a lot of cedar decks and fences but have used pressure treated lumber for the structure.